While index.html does not give an error, javascript gives an error when index.php is processed
I don't get any errors in index.html, but when I do index.php I get the error:

sidebarmenu.js:88 uncaught typeerror: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'closest')
At htmldocument. (sidebarmenu.js:88:33)

Line 88:
Var closestnav = elements. Closest("nav[class^=sidebar-nav]");

Why don't I get an error in index.html? Why do I get an error in index.php and the sidebar is broken?

You haven't provided any code to help to determine what's going on. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. Why are you expecting two files to yield the same result?

The code shown reads Closest, but the error indicates closest.  And what is Var?  Did you mean var?  JavaScript is case-sensitive.  Are you sure this is the correct code?  The error itself is simply telling you that elements is null.  Of course, the code shown never defines elements or sets any value to it, so we can't really know why it's null.  What debugging have you done?  (If you're not familiar with your browser's development/debugging tools, now is a good time to start.)

Why don't I get an error in index.html...presumably because either there's no javascript code on that page, or if there is, none of it is faulty or tries to select elements that don't exist in the page

Why do I get an error in index.php...Hard to tell exactly without a [mre] of the issue but, as others have said, your elements variable is null. Presumably either you forgot to declare it, or it's the result of an action which failed to match any results

Administrators, please do not remove it, it is not a duplicate!....please demonstrate why then, by adding some information which differentiates your situation from the one described in the duplicate. A [mre] of the issue would be a good start. Simply stating that it's not a duplicate, without any evidence, isn't going to change anyone's mind. Reminder: [ask]
